# Failing to push the proper element data to an array

Tags: javascript, queryselector

I'm trying to have the same data I've set in a function - in a different function as an object key in an array and it keeps pushing the same number (12). Also, I'm trying to get a specific word from the src of an image within a loop. How can I make the src a temporary string? (the console.log line)

Edit following a comment to make it more clear:
Currently, the  flag.setAttribute('data-flag', i); line sets the data-flag of ALL the 12 flags to 12, while I want to set them individually (data-flag 1 for flag 1, data-flag2 for flag 2 and so on). Another problem: I want to slice a specific word from the src of the images within a loop (for example, if images srcs are 1-smile.gif, 2-frown.gif, 3-laugh.gif, I want to slice the word following the dash in the src of each image, using the loop, and then storing it in a variable).

Would very much appreciate your help.

```
'use strict';

var gBgEyesShift = false;

var gQuestions = [];

var gFlagsDiv;

function init() {
    bgEyesMovement();
    getFlag();
    generateQuestions();
}

function generateQuestions() {
    var flagId = getFlag().getAttribute('data-flag');
    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        gQuestions.push({id: flagId});
    }
}

function getFlag(flag) {
    gFlagsDiv = document.querySelector('.flags');

    for (var i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
        flag = new Image(150, 150);
        flag.src = 'img/' + i + '.gif';
        flag.setAttribute('class', 'flag');
        flag.setAttribute('data-flag', i);
        gFlagsDiv.appendChild(flag);
    }
    console.log(flag.src.toString().slice('gif'));
    return flag;
}
```

```
    <body onload="init()">
        <div class="flags">
            
        </div>
```

Comment: not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @SagarV Currently, the  flag.setAttribute('data-flag', i); line sets the data-flag of ALL the 12 flags to 12, while I want to set them individually (data-flag 1 for flag 1, data-flag2 for flag 2 and so on). Another problem: I want to slice a specific word from the src of the images within a loop (for example, if images srcs are 1-smile.gif, 2-frown.gif, 3-laugh.gif, I want to slice the word following the dash in the src of each image, using the loop, and then storing it in a variable).